# How can I display certain text from a javascript inside the html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just starting to learn javascript, so I don't know how everything works. I have this function:

```
<div id="box1">
  <a id="link1">Link</a>
  <div><script>
   function script() {

var producto,cantidad,precio,tp,imagen;

producto=prompt("Ingresar producto:");
cantidad=parseInt(prompt("Ingresar cantidad:"));

switch (producto) {
  case "disco":
    precio=200;imagen="disco.jpg";break;
  case "micro":
    precio=800;imagen="micro.jpg";break;
  case "placa":
    precio=500;imagen="placa.jpg";break;
  case "memoria":
    precio=800;imagen="memoria.jpg";break;
  case "case":
    precio=100;imagen="case.jpg";break;
  case "tarjeta":
    precio=300;imagen="tarjeta.jpg";break;
  default:
    alert("No se encuentra el producto en lista");
}
tp=precio*cantidad;

document.write( "Producto: "+producto+"<br>");
document.write("Precio: "+precio+"<br>");
document.write("Cantidad: "+cantidad+"<br>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Total a pagar: "+tp+"<br>");
document.write("<img src="+imagen+">");
};
document.getElementById('link1').onclick = function () {
script();
};
</script></div>
```

When I click the "link1" the result appears in a blank page, how can I display the info inside the same page?

Comment: `how can I display the info inside the same page?` don't use `document.write`

Comment: By "how can I display the info inside the same page", where do you actually wants to show the info?

Comment: You can use document.getElementById('link1').innerHTML https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: So if I want to show the info inside a <div id="box2"> what should I change?

Comment: document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML will definitely do the job for you. But if you are doing this for a lot of places then your code will start getting replicated and may become tedious to manage it. This is where you might want to have a look at https://angularjs.org/ as a framework for your apps or http://handlebarsjs.com/ for template binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far what I understood is that "You're trying to display information on a same page using javascript"? If you're trying something similar to this then continue reading... 
**How Is This Possible?**

 This is possible if you create a `<div>` tag on same page and assign an id to it & then use javascript DOM to show text in it. Let's start doing it.
Step 1:-

```
<div id="TextGoesHere"></div>
<a id="link1">Link</a>
<script>
   function script() {

var producto,cantidad,precio,tp,imagen;

producto=prompt("Ingresar producto:");
cantidad=parseInt(prompt("Ingresar cantidad:"));

switch (producto) {
  case "disco":
    precio=200;imagen="disco.jpg";break;
  case "micro":
    precio=800;imagen="micro.jpg";break;
  case "placa":
    precio=500;imagen="placa.jpg";break;
  case "memoria":
    precio=800;imagen="memoria.jpg";break;
  case "case":
    precio=100;imagen="case.jpg";break;
  case "tarjeta":
    precio=300;imagen="tarjeta.jpg";break;
  default:
    alert("No se encuentra el producto en lista");
}
tp=precio*cantidad;
var div = document.getElementById("TextGoesHere");
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "Producto: "+producto+"<br>";
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + Precio: "+precio+"<br>";
// Similarly you just have to copy above line paste again and replace variables. 
};
document.getElementById('link1').onclick = function () {
script();
};
</script>
```

**What .innerHTML does?**
If you are familiar with other languages such as java or etc there is function of append() which concatenates new element with previous one. Similarly 
.innerHTML can be used to append new element or text into tag preceding with DOM.

**Tip:**
try to use `type="text/javascript"` in `<script> tag` because when you validate your code with w3c validator your code won't be validated because of this :)

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful :)

Comment: My pleasure :). If you found my answer helpful please vote up my answer .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a div where you want to display the results, for example:

```
<div id = "blablabla"></div><br>
```

Then use

```
document.getElementById('blablabla').innerHTML="Producto: "+producto+"<br>";
```

in your JavaScript to display the results in the div.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
document.write( "Producto: "+producto+"<br>");
```

With

```
document.getElementById('link1').innerHTML="Producto: "+producto+"<br>";
```